How can I set the compatibility mode for an executable from inside a C++ program?
I have been reading how to do this via a command prompt. I tried that. It worked. Then I tried to do it in C++ and failed. I expect this to have been an issue for someone in the past, but I did not find the question and a valid answer elsewhere. Please point me to where this has been asked before for C++ and validly answered. Not for Visual C++. Not for C. I am using CodeBlocks on a MS Windows system.

it is simply done using reg.exe, How can I set the compatibility mode for an executable from the command line?, translating that to C++ using win32 API the following code seems to work using codeblocks 20.03 using MINGW 4.3.5 gcc 7.3.0 (2018 build)
#include <Windows.h>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    HKEY hKey = NULL;
    LPCTSTR subKey = TEXT("Software\\Microsoft\\Windows NT\\CurrentVersion\\AppCompatFlags\\Layers");

    if (RegCreateKeyEx(HKEY_CURRENT_USER, subKey, 0, NULL, REG_OPTION_NON_VOLATILE, KEY_ALL_ACCESS, NULL, &hKey, NULL) == ERROR_SUCCESS) {
        LPCTSTR valueName = TEXT("C:\\Program Files\\MyApp\\Test.exe");
        LPCTSTR valueData = TEXT("WIN7RTM");

        if (RegSetValueEx(hKey, valueName, 0, REG_SZ, (LPBYTE)valueData, (lstrlen(valueData) + 1) * sizeof(TCHAR)) == ERROR_SUCCESS) {
            std::cout << "String value added successfully.\n";
        } else {
            std::cout << "Failed to set the string value.\n";
        }

        RegCloseKey(hKey);
    } else {
        std::cout << "Failed to create the registry key.\n";
    }

    return 0;
}

you can change HKEY_CURRENT_USER to HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE to force it on the entire system, and then it can only be removed by modifying the registry, source: The Program Compatibility Assistant - Part Two
for a list of compatibility values refer to the following source How to Control Compatibility Mode
